# Not able to get getjson to work on highstock

Tags: javascript, csv, getjson, highcharts

I'm having some problems with importing a csv in order to get the highstock graph.
I'm using the same code as the ohlc example (which works fine locally) but with another CSV which is created on my localhost by php.

PHP to get the CSV

```
<?PHP

// Declare the new variable as an array
$arrCSV = array();

// Open the CSV file
if (($handle = fopen("http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=AAPL&d=7&e=7&f=2012&g=d&a=8&b=7&c=1984&ignore=.csv", "r")) !==FALSE)
{

// Set the parent array key to 0
$key = 0;
// While there is data available loop through unlimited times (0) using separator (,)
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ",")) !==FALSE) {

    // Count the total keys in each row
    $c = count($data);
    //print  $c . "<BR>"; // <------ 7 o numero de colunas

    //Populate the array
    If ($key != 0) {
        $arrCSV[$key-1][0] = strtotime($data[0])*1000; //Time
        $arrCSV[$key-1][1] = $data[1];            //Open
        $arrCSV[$key-1][2] = $data[2];            //High
        $arrCSV[$key-1][3] = $data[3];            //Low
        $arrCSV[$key-1][4] = $data[6];            //Adj Close
        $arrCSV[$key-1][5] = $data[5];            //Volume
    }

    $key++;
} // end while

$keymax = $key;

// Close the CSV file
fclose($handle);
} // end if

print "?(/* AAPL historical OHLC data from the Google Finance API */<BR>";
echo json_encode($arrCSV,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
print ");";

?>
```

Code to import and create the graph:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
      <title>Highstock Example</title>

          <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
   $.getJSON('http://localhost/teste03.php', function(data) {
      console.log("1");
      // create the chart
      chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
         chart : {
            renderTo : 'container'
         },

         rangeSelector : {
            selected : 2
         },

         title : {
            text : 'AAPL Stock Price'
         },

         series : [{
            type : 'ohlc',
            name : 'AAPL Stock Price',
            data : data,
            dataGrouping : {
               units : [[
                  'week', // unit name
                  [1] // allowed multiples
               ], [
                  'month', 
                  [1, 2, 3, 4, 6]
               ]]
            }
         }]
      });
   });
});

      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
<script src="js/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="js/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 500px; min-width: 500px"></div>
   </body>
</html>
```

In the end it just get me a blank page...
On the chrome console I'm not able to get the console log that is inside the getjson and it reports as if everything is ok:

```
[23:39:29.980] GET http://localhost/TraderMananger/Highstock/ohlc4.htm [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 1ms]
[23:39:30.036] GET http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 87ms]
[23:39:30.055] GET http://localhost/TraderMananger/Highstock/js/highstock.js [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 1ms]
[23:39:30.073] GET http://localhost/TraderMananger/Highstock/js/modules/exporting.js [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 1ms]
[23:39:30.219] GET http://localhost/TraderMananger/Highstock/teste04.php [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 2056ms]
```

Help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is solved now, the issue was in the chos added before and after the json_encode, there is no need to add them

```
print "?(/* AAPL historical OHLC data from the Google Finance API */<BR>";
echo json_encode($arrCSV,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
print ");";
```

So, removing them it solved the issue.